# Creating a Xamarin Form Library in Visual Studio Mac

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to develop a library for `Xamarin` Forms just like how we do in native iOS and android, like `.framework` or .a for iOS and .aar and .jar for Java Android.

I researched a lot and saw that we can create a nuget Packages based on Platform dependent  environment .. But In my case I want to create a SDK which will only make HTTp calls and hence I don't want to use any platform dependent code .

I also found that we can create .Net Standard Library, but didn't get any useful material or Link to work Forward.

My Requirement is to create a SDK which can be used in `Xamarin` Forms Project . Can SomeOne Please guide me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just create a .NET Standard library project.  What specifically don't you understand how to do?

Comment: So How to test that Library.. I created the Library and imported it.. But its not Auto-populating any class which is defined there

Comment: This is pretty basic C#.  Based on your vague description of the problem there's really not much I can suggest.  Did you add a ref to your library from your main project?  Are the classes you're trying to use in the library public?

Comment: Yes... I added the Library and all classes are Public... The Problem is that If I write the class and method Name then its working fine.. The compiler is not Auto  Suggesting class and Method Name

Comment: that sounds like an IDE/Intellisense problem